# How can I get automatic dependency resolution in my scala scripts?

Tags: scala

I'm just learning scala coming out of the groovy/java world. My first script requires a 3rd party library TagSoup for XML/HTML parsing, and I'm loath to have to add it the old school way: that is, downloading TagSoup from its developer website, and then adding it to the class path.

Is there a way to resolve third party libraries in my scala scripts? I'm thinking Ivy, I'm thinking Grape.

Ideas?

---

The answer that worked best for me was to install n8:

```
curl https://raw.github.com/n8han/conscript/master/setup.sh | sh
cs harrah/xsbt --branch v0.11.0
```

Then I could import tagsoup fairly easily example.scala

```
  /***
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
          "org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup" % "tagsoup" % "1.2.1"
      )
  */

  def getLocation(address:String) = {
      ...
  }
```

And run using scalas:

```
  scalas example.scala
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While the answer is SBT, it could have been more helpful where *scripts* are regarded. See, SBT has a special thing for scripts, as described [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Scripts.html). Once you get `scalas` installed, either by installing [conscript](https://github.com/n8han/conscript) and then running `cs harrah/xsbt --branch v0.11.0`, or simply by writing it yourself more or less like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -Dsbt.main.class=sbt.ScriptMain \
     -Dsbt.boot.directory=/home/user/.sbt/boot \
     -jar sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

Then you can write your script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env scalas
!#

/***
scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-twitter" % "0.8.3",
  "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-http" % "0.8.3"
)
*/

import dispatch.{ json, Http, Request }
import dispatch.twitter.Search
import json.{ Js, JsObject }

def process(param: JsObject) = {
  val Search.text(txt)        = param
  val Search.from_user(usr)   = param
  val Search.created_at(time) = param

  "(" + time + ")" + usr + ": " + txt
}

Http.x((Search("#scala") lang "en") ~> (_ map process foreach println))
```

You may also be interested in paulp's [xsbtscript](https://github.com/paulp/xsbtscript), which creates an `xsbtscript` shell that has the same thing as `scalas` (I guess the latter was based on the former), with the advantage that, *without either conscript or sbt installed*, you can get it ready with this:

```
curl https://raw.github.com/paulp/xsbtscript/master/setup.sh | sh
```

Note that it installs sbt and conscript.

And there's also paulp's [sbt-extras](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras), which is an alternative "sbt" command line, with more options. Note that it's still sbt, just the shell script that starts it is more intelligent.

Comment: I'm gonna try this - thanks, it sounds exactly like what I'm looking for.

Comment: // note: I made an up-to-date answer based on yours. (It was actually written from scratch so I made it separate.)

Answer (score 8):

SBT (Simple Build Tool) seems to be the build tool of choice in the Scala world.  It supports a number of different dependency resolution mechanisms: https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Library-Management

Answer (score 7):

*Placed as an answer cause it doesn't fit in comment length constraint*.

In addition to @Chris answer, I would like to recommend you some commons for sbt (which I personally think is absolutely superb). Although sbt denote *Simple* Build Tool, sometimes it is not so easy for first-timers to setup project with sbt (all this things with layouts, configs, and so on).

Use [giter](https://github.com/n8han/giter8) (g8) to create new project with predefined template (which g8 fetches from github.com). There are templates for [Android app](https://github.com/gseitz/android-sbt-project.g8), [unfiltered](https://github.com/softprops/unfiltered.g8) and [more](https://github.com/n8han/giter8/wiki/giter8-templates). Sometimes they are include some of the dependencies by default.
To create layout just type:

```
g8 gseitz/android-sbt-project
```

(An example for Android app)

Alternatively, use [np](https://github.com/softprops/np) pluggin for sbt, which provides interactive type-through way to create new project and basic layout.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info - I think sbt is the basic answer I'm looking for but your additional info will be helpful as I do more scala I'm sure :)

Answer (score 2):

A corrected and simplified version of the current main answer: use `scalas`.

You have to compose your script of 3 parts. One would be `sbt`, another would be a very simple wrapper around SBT called `scalas`, the last one is your custom script. Note that the first two scripts can be installed either globally (/usr/bin/, ~/bin/) or locally (in the same directory).

- the first part is `sbt`. If you already have it installed then good. If not, you can either install it, or use a very cool script from paulp: https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/blob/master/sbt  BTW, that thing is a charming way to use sbt on Unix. Although not available on windows. Anyways...
- the second part is `scalas`. It's just an entrypoint to SBT.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec /path/to/sbt -Dsbt.main.class=sbt.ScriptMain -sbt-create \
    -Dsbt.boot.directory=$HOME/.sbt/boot \
    "$@"
```

- the last part is your custom script. Example:

```scala
#!/usr/bin/env scalas
/***
scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.joda"            %   "joda-convert"      % "1.5",
    "joda-time"           %   "joda-time"         % "2.3"
)
*/

import org.joda.time._

println(DateTime.now())
//println(DateTime.now().minusHours(12).dayOfMonth())
```

Answer (score 0):

What Daniel said. Although it's worth mentioning that the [sbt docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Scripts.html) carefully label this functionality "experimental".

Indeed, if you try to run the embedded script with scalaVersion := "2.10.3", you'll get

```
not found: value !#
```

Luckily, the !# script header-closer is unnecessary here, so you can leave it out.

Under scalaVersion := "2.10.3", the script will need to have the file extension ".scala"; using the bash shell script file extension, ".sh", won't work.

Also, it isn't clear to me that the latest version of Dispatch (0.11.0) supports dispatch-twitter, which is used in the example.

For more about header-closers in this context, see Alvin Alexander's [blog post](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-shell-script-example-exec-syntax) on Scala scripting, or section 14.10 of his [Scala Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026914.do).

Answer (score 0):

I have a `build.gradle` file with the following task:

```
task classpath(dependsOn: jar) << {
    println "CLASSPATH=${tasks.jar.archivePath}:${configurations.runtime.asPath}"
}
```

Then, in my Scala script:

```
#!
script_dir=$(cd $(dirname "$0") >/dev/null; pwd -P)

classpath=$(cd ${script_dir} && ./gradlew classpath | grep '^CLASSPATH=' | sed -e 's|^CLASSPATH=||')

PATH=${SCALA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g" exec scala -classpath ${classpath} "$0" "$0" "$@"
!#
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that we don't *need* a separate `scalas` executable in our `PATH`, since we can use the [self-executing shell script](https://www.matteomattei.com/create-self-contained-installer-in-bash-that-extracts-archives-and-perform-actitions) trick.

Here's an example script, which reads its own content (via the `$0` variable), chops off everything before an arbitrary marker (`__BEGIN_SCRIPT__`) and runs `sbt` on the result. We use process substitution to pretend this calculated content is a real file. One problem with this approach is that `sbt` will seek within the given file, i.e. it doesn't read it sequentially. That stops it working with the `<(foo)` form of process substitution, as found in `bash`; however `zsh` has a `=(foo)` form which *is* seekable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
set -e

# Find the line # in this file ($0) after the line beginning __BEGIN_SCRIPT__
LINENUM=$(awk '/^__BEGIN_SCRIPT__/ {print NR + 1; exit 0; }' "$0")

sbtRun() {
    # Run the sbt command, such that it will fetch dependencies and execute a
    # script
    sbt -Dsbt.main.class=sbt.ScriptMain \
        -sbt-create \
        -Dsbt.boot.directory="$HOME/.sbt/boot" \
        "$@"
}

# Run SBT on the contents of this file, starting at LINENUM
sbtRun =(tail -n+"$LINENUM" "$0")

exit 0

__BEGIN_SCRIPT__
/***
scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.joda"            %   "joda-convert"      % "1.5",
    "joda-time"           %   "joda-time"         % "2.3"
)
*/

import org.joda.time._

println(DateTime.now())
```